# 'or' in matlab regexp

Tags: regex, matlab

I want to extract whether a string contains 'jack' or 'jill' and return the name.  Something like this:

```
name = regexp('/home/jack/Documents','jack | jill','match');
name = 'jack'
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

If the issue is related to spaces, how can I keep them inside the pattern, but still match the names?

Comment: Get rid of the spaces around the pipe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `'jack|jill'` pattern as the spaces inside a pattern are *meaningful*:

```
pattern = 'jack|jill';
s = '/home/jack/Documents';
name = regexp(s,pattern,'match');
```

The `name` now contains `jack`.

If you want to make the regex engine ignore all the unescaped whitespaces in the pattern, add `(?x)` at the start of the pattern:

```
pattern = '(?x)jack | jill';
```

See [the docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com):

> `(?x)`
>   Ignore space characters and comments when matching. Use `'\ '` and `'\#'` to match space and `#` characters.